# NSWindow restorable not always working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowrestoration

I have checked the restorable option on my NSWindow
When I move my application and change its size and close/reopen my application it sets the window size and position to the last size and position

but this doesn't happen on every computer where i test it. it only happens to a few computers

they don't have special settings regarding the resume.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> But this doesn't happen on every computer where I test it. It only
>   happens to a few computers. They don't have special settings regarding
>   the resume.

Actually, they do. Take a look into the System Preferences > General pane. There should be an option named “Close windows when quitting an application” which is responsible for the restoration behavior. Additionally, in OS X Mountain Lion, Apple changed default behavior and now the app restores its state only when you quit using Command-Option-Q.

So, you probably should check which OS X version is installed on another Mac, and which preference is selected in the General pane. Hope this helps!

Comment: I really wish there was a way for us to check the state of that checkbox.

Comment: Great answer! Couldn't figure out why it wouldn't restore until this

Comment: Actually, we _can_ query the state of this checkbox: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows"]` or `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows")` gets the _inverse_ of the checkbox. That is, if the box is unchecked, the value in the user defaults is `true`.

Comment: None of this is valid anymore.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you should know is that checking the "Restorable" option in IB only changes a window property. The actual restoring and saving is in your hands.

First, you have to conform to the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol and implement the 
`-window:willEncodeRestorableState:state` and `-window:didDecodeRestorableState:` 
methods that encode and decode your window properties (For example your windows frame, which you obviously get by calling `[myWindow frame]`).

You also need to conform to the `NSWindowRestoration` protocol and implement `+restoreWindowWithIdentifier:state:completionHandler:`. (make sure you set your class to restoration class, with the `setRestorationClass` method)

For additional, more in depth, information, you can visit [this Apple Documentation document here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26).

Comment: I did that, and on my computer its working. i have placed a log statement in that method and it logs perfectly, but on my partner's computer ( who isn't a developer (i created an debug build)) it isn't working and the log statement doesn't show up..

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to restore the window's frame use `setFrameAutosaveName:`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SavingWindowPosition.html