# Remember window open/close in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My Cocoa application in objective-c has two windows, A and B, that contain helper functionality. The user might not always want these windows to be open (think brush size or color wheel in Gimp). I want the application to remember whether each of these windows was open or closed between each instantiation of the program. For instance:

1. User opens the program, and both Windows A and B are open
2. The user closes window A but not window B
3. User closes the program
4. User opens the program
5. Only window B is open, window A is closed
6. User opens window A
7. User closes the program
8. User opens the program
9. Both windows B and A are open

Is there a way to remember this type of history in Cocoa? Google has not been my friend in this search.

Comment: You should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779681/nswindow-restorable-not-always-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults for this purposes. It's key-value based data structure, which is saves between lunches.

In your example you can do something like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:aPresentedFlag forKey:@"aPresented"];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey@"aPresented"]) {
//show your aWindow
}
```